# Can I RDP through mstsc and run a script on that remote desktop?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, remote-access, rdp

I'm writing a script which needs to RDP to a few servers, do processes there and then come back.

`mstsc /v:<computer>` by itself looks great as it's security/credential prompt is the same as if you manually executed it.

However, after some research it appears that's meant to be a command line utility and nothing more because trying things like:

```
mstsc /v:104.209.198.181 | Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {"New-Item C:\Users\<me>\Desktop\Success.txt -ItemType file"}
```

doesn't work.

So I tried `Enter-PSSession <computer> -Credential $env:UserName` which people use but it looks like a mess to deal with compared to `mstsc` because it looks primitive (an article I read yesterday tried to say this type of prompt is ALWAYS a phishing scam which obviously it's not but try telling management), it doesn't auto-populate domains, and I get a WinRM error which I'm sure will be a rabbit hole.

So is it possible to RDP with `mstsc` and then pipe commands to it so they're executed on that computer?

Comment: https://serverfault.com ?

Comment: MSTSC is primitive compared to Enter-PSSession. WinRM is not a rabbit hole. Almost everything you want to do with GUI, you can do with PowerShell. What is it that you are trying to do anyway?

Comment: Maybe post a question about your WinRM errors instead of writing it off as a "rabbit hole"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.  You cannot initiate some kind of pipe using [`MSTSC.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc).

You can, however, use `PSRemoting` to send the command like you're trying to do already:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName '<FQDN>' -ScriptBlock {
    New-Item -Path "$HOME\Desktop\Success.txt" -ItemType File
}
```

If you don't know the FQDN, then look up the IP using DNS:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('104.209.198.181')
```

---

All this failing.. you can fall back on WMI, but you don't get any console feedback:

```
$WmiArgs = @{
    'Class'        = 'Win32_Process'
    'Name'         = 'Create'
    'ArgumentList' = 'powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "New-Item -Path $HOME\Desktop\Success.txt -ItemType File"'
    'ComputerName' = '104.209.198.181'
}
Invoke-WmiMethod @WmiArgs
```

---

While I tested the above is working, you can shorthand even this!

```
([wmiclass]'\\104.209.198.181\root\cimv2:win32_process').
    Create('powershell -NoP -NonI -W Hidden -C "New-Item -Path $HOME\Desktop\Success.txt -ItemType File"')
```

With this method, however, you cannot pass credentials.

Comment: Technically speaking, you *can* pass credentials if you use `cmd.exe /c "runas ....."`. But I'm not even about to attempt that abomination of string escaping, and you have to previously have executed `runas /savecred` with the same account for it to work.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest And if there is containerization of workstations in play, `runas.exe` may not play nice.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest `$HOME` resolves as an automatic variable on the endpoint when the command is executed.  It will run into issues if the username has spaces in it, however.

Comment: There are many hoops and limitations that come with runas. I was simply stating it's technically possible if someone wanted to pursue it.

Comment: Doh - I removed the comment. Long day, you are right